# Need an Ubuntu 15.04 sudoers file

Tags: sudo, 15.04

I accidentally deleted mine by trying to edit it with `emacs`. Can anyone share a default copy?

Comment: The file clearly says to use visudo. Keep that in mind for future. Also , use google. The default is posted on ubuntu help page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: Always, always create a .bak file of the file you want to edit before you work on that file in the event you mess up so you have a copy of it.

Comment: I didn't even actually edit it. Just poof, 2 curly brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Learn how to solve this problem just boot from Ubuntu live disk and copy `/etc/sudoers` file to the installed Ubuntu partition's `/etc` directory

Anyway this is a default one:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```